# How can I use GPU to accelerate the NIntegrate function in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, gpu

Here is what I met:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTV8Q.jpg)

I need to do the calculation of that complicated function with parameter t, 
is there any way to use the GPU for acceleration?

Comment: Include your complete code not just image.

Comment: read this, http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GPUComputing.html, then go to mathematica.stackexchange.com for further questions.